# How do I set up an 'onKeyPress' handler on a <canvas> in react?

Tags: javascript, events, reactjs

I am familiar with React and its event system, but I can't seem to get the onKeyPress event to fire on a `<canvas>` element.  In fact, I can't get it to fire on a `<div>` either.

Here is the relevant code

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <canvas onKeyPress={() => console.log('fired')} />
        )
    }
}
```

It works fine if I change the `<canvas>` to be an `<input>`, but does not work for `<div>`.  Does this mean that react simply does not support keyPress events on canvas elements?  What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just assign `tabIndex` to the element for getting the focus.

```
<canvas tabIndex="0" onKeyPress={ () => console.log( 'fired' ) } />
```

Comment: May depend on the React version or if you're using TypeScript, but I needed to use `tabIndex={0}` as `tabIndex` takes a `number`.

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    alert('keydown');
        }, false);
```

Check if you can fire the above event :)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I was hoping to use react's synthetic event system