# Using event handlers in canvas functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the component.

```
const CanvasComponent = (props) => {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const [controller, setController] = useState({
        a: false,
        shift: false,
    });

    return (
        <canvas
            ref = { canvasRef }
            width = { 1000 }
            height = { 1000 }
        />
    );
};
```

I would like to create event handlers on the canvas so that, on keydown, the controller state is modified to flip `a` to true. Same with `shift`.

I've been reading about custom `useEventHandler` hooks, but any references that are specifically about canvases seem to only use mouse events.

I want to create a custom hook that makes the process of adding events for specific keys easy and elegant. I've tried several things already, and none of them seem to work as I want them to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up an 'onKeyPress' handler on a <canvas> in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117001/how-do-i-set-up-an-onkeypress-handler-on-a-canvas-in-react)

Comment: @soulLess It helps. I was hoping to actually reference the ref and bind events to the canvas. This solution feels like a workaround.